# How can temporal data with multiple paths be shown in one plot?

Tags: plotting, time-series

I am trying to plot `SunPosition` for an entire year.  The examples I have seen plot a single day or one exact time across the entire year, not the full data set. (NOTE: the example code has a three day date range so as speed the trial calculations)

The data is generated with the code below:

```
loc = GeoPosition[{45, 0}]

tz = 0

sunriseToSunset[loc_, date_] := 
 SunPosition[loc, 
  DateRange[Sunrise[loc, date], Sunset[loc, date], {10, "Minute"}]]

dr = DateRange[DateObject[{2015, 1, 1}, TimeZone -> tz], 
   DateObject[{2015, 1, 3}, TimeZone -> tz]];

{dt, foo} = 
  AbsoluteTiming@
   TemporalData@
    ParallelMap[sunriseToSunset[loc, #] &, dr, Method -> Automatic];
```

The output `foo` is `TemporalData` with three paths.  Each point in the list is `{date, {azimuth, altitude}}`

I would like to plot altitude vs azimuth for all three days (Paths) on the same chart at the same time.

Subsequently I would want to append the list with data calculated from the `foo`.  For instance, attach `Cos[altitude]` to each point so the temporal data becomes `{date, {azimuth, altitude, Cos[altitude]}}`

Comment: Greetings! To make the most of Mma.SE please **take the [tour] now**. **Help us to help you**, write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimum** working examples of **code and data in [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: Have you considered the display problem? I can not see how you can make a single plot with 365 paths containing an average of 120 points each without producing a visual nightmare. Perhaps you might break it up into 12 monthly plots?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The plots are easy. First, as an opaque "object", `TemporalData` has a `"Properties"` method, e.g.

```
foo["Properties"]
(* {"Components", "DateList", "DatePath", "DatePaths", "Dates", 
"FirstDates", "FirstTimes", "FirstValues", "LastDates", "LastTimes", 
"LastValues", "Part", "Path", "PathCount", "PathFunction", 
"PathFunctions", "PathLength", "PathLengths", "Paths", "PathTimes", 
"SliceData", "SliceDistribution", "TimeList", "Times", 
"ValueDimensions", "ValueList", "Values"} *)
```

At first look, `"Values"` would be the correct property to use, but it only returns data from one path, so `"Paths"` is the correct one with the ordinates extracted using `Part` which can be supplied to `ListPlot`, e.g.

```
ListPlot@foo["Paths"][[All, All, 2]]
```

Comment: Your code solution did not work for me. With modification from `ListPlot@foo["Path"][[All, All, 2]]` to `ListPlot@foo["Paths"][[All, All, 2]]` the plotting works as I wanted. Thank you.

Comment: @MBO so it was an obvious typo. They happen.